# AlertDialog doesn't show on second call

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

i am working on a project where i have to check if there is a roll of paper in the printer before printing. 
here is my code :

```
private void ImpressionTicket() {
    new Print(cardNo, mBaseActivity,transEntity);
    while (Print.print_state.equals("true")) ;//true
    if(Print.print_state.equals("Paper Lack")){
        PrintFail( -1005);
    }
    else {
        PrintDialog();
        while (PrintDial.equals("HERE")) ;
        ImpresssionDialog();
        new PrintClient(cardNo, mBaseActivity, transEntity);
        while (PrintClient.print_state_Client) ;
        getActivity().finish();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CashActivity1.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
  }
```

Her is the PrintFail() code:

```
private void PrintFail(final int i) {
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            pwdAlertDialogistrsE.setTitle("Papier introuvable");
            TRScheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    pwdAlertDialogistrsE.dismiss();
                      ImpressionTicket();

                }
            });
            switch (i) {
                case -1005:
                    pwdAlertDialogistrsE.setMessage("\n"+"\n"+"Insérez papier puis validez "+"\n"+"\n"+"\n"+"\n"+"\n");
                    break;
            }
            pwdAlertDialogistrsE.show();
            getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

            int displayWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
            int displayHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

            // Initialize a new window manager layout parameters
            WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();

            // Copy the alert dialog window attributes to new layout parameter instance
            layoutParams.copyFrom(pwdAlertDialogistrsE.getWindow().getAttributes());
            int dialogWindowWidth = (int) (displayWidth * 0.9f);
            // Set alert dialog height equal to screen height 70%
            int dialogWindowHeight = (int) (displayHeight * 0.8f);

            // Set the width and height for the layout parameters
            // This will bet the width and height of alert dialog
            layoutParams.width = dialogWindowWidth;
            layoutParams.height = dialogWindowHeight;

            // Apply the newly created layout parameters to the alert dialog window
            pwdAlertDialogistrsE.getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);

        }
    });
}
```

the code is supposed to shwo the alert dialog if there is no paper, so that the user inserts it. After that the user click on OK button and the ticket is printed.
now the pblrm is that after ading the paper and clicking on Ok the AlertDialog in the else statment does not show. 
Anyone have any idea why.

Comment: your current code doesn't show any event occurrence for paper insert so your else part will be executed when your `ImpressionTicket()` method is called again.

Comment: thank you for your response, but i am calling the ImpressionTicket() after the PrintFail() is called but the dialog does not show.